# How to get OpenReadCompleted result from method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want get a result from webClient_OpenReadCompleted, and i want get response in getMethod. But in this code, at first getMehod works and only then, when getMethod finished,  webClient_OpenReadCompleted works. How to get a result in getMethod?

p.s. It's all on Windows Phone

```
public string apiUri = "https://api.vk.com/method/";
public string response = "";

public void getMethod(string parameters)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
    string uri = apiUri + parameters + "&access_token=" + access_token;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
}

void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
    response = xml.ToString();
}

public void statusGet(string uid)
{
    getMethod("status.get.xml?uid" + uid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return data, I would suggest you set up
1) Custom EventArgs to hold data
2) Custom event.

When you get the data, you set the event args and then set the event so subscriber gets the data.

Comment: I didn't try it, but i asked one Senior c# Developer and he advised to do this:

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but i asked one Senior c# Developer and he advised to  create bool and write this:

```
bool work;

public void getMethod(string parameters)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
    string uri = apiUri + parameters + "&access_token=" + access_token;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
    work = true;
    while(work) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
}

void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
    response = xml.ToString();
    work = false;
}
```

Now, question is not actual, because i changed the architecture of my app.